# dynamic UILabel in UIView increase memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiview

I have an `UILabel` pinter in my `UIView` (using ARC). 
I dynamically create a lot of text and override the the same pointer every time. 
I thought, that if I use the same pointer all the time, and override it with the new objects, they still be in my View, but the pointer of them will be deallocated. But as I see, my memory increase all the time, if the text was changed and the `drawRect` executed. Maybe someone know the better way to do that, or to fix this memory issue.

**UPDATE: Code**

```
@interface Bars : UIView{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictCopy;
    UILabel *pivotLabel;
}
for (a lot of times) {
pivotLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
pivotLabel.text = pivotText;
pivotLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
pivotLabel.textColor = self.color;
[self addSubview:pivotLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new label as a subview the parent view retains it. Nilling a pointer is not enough to remove it. To remove a label, do this:

```
        [self.myLabel removeFromSuperview];
        self.myLabel = nil;
```

Comment: Yes, that fix my memory issue, but also remove the text from my View. Me like it  ... pause ... NOT. I need the text stay there.

Comment: If you will add more subviews to your view, the memory will increase. There is no way around it.

Comment: maybe the way to clear and dealloc all the stuff of uiview and then drawrect again?

Comment: I agree with @Adam. If you need to add different UILabels in different locations with different value then each must be allocated separately.